# Is "parentActivityName" necessary ?

Tags: android

Let's assume that we have Activity and we want to provide Up Navigation. 
When we want to start this Activity we fire simple method:

```
public static void startActivity(Context context) {
        Intent productIntent = new Intent(context, CustomActivity.class);
        productIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(productIntent);
}
```

The problem is that we want to start it from different Activities, and it's hard to define it parent Activity. So in that case is it necessary to add in AndroidManifest.xml attribute `parentActivityName` ?

Comment: No, not necessary, but it provides easy back/up navigation

Comment: No it is not necessary. I never use it.

Comment: So if I won't use it, I won't be able to add navigation back button on actionbar?